# Google Dataflow pipeline stuck on GroupByKey

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

There seem to be many alike questions/issues with a Beam pipeline being stuck in GroupByKey, but after a whole day of trying different settings for PubSubIO and Window triggers, I still have not come any further.

I have a PubSub topic producing a steady stream of data:
[image]
When starting my pipeline in Dataflow a bunch of elements are added. Hereafter, the number of elements remains the same. The data watermark increases slowly and is around 10-11 minutes behind current time, which coincides with the message retention time of the PubSub subscription of 10 minutes. I have tried different setups for reading PubSub, with and without attributes, adding the timestamp myself, etc. In this job it is just a vanilla read without attributes relying on Google to compute the timestamps.

Here I am trying to run my pipeline, which doesn't do any grouping by key:
[image]
I tried a lot of Window setups. My goals is a sliding window of 30 minutes duration every 1 minute, but here I am just trying to get it to work with a FixedWindow of 1 minute. I also tried a lot of different triggers with both early and late firings added. In this job, I did not specify anything, ie. it should use the default trigger.

The job id is 2019-11-01_06_38_28-2654303843876161133

Does anyone have any suggestions on what else I can try to get some element through the GBK?

**Update:**

I have simplified my pipeline to continue troubleshooting the issue using the hint in one of the comments to look at the watermark at reading the PubSub messages.

I have an attribute on the PubSub message that I use as timestamp (`.withTimestampAttribute(...)`). Logging the `timestamp()` in `ProcessContext` does give the correct timestamp and window assignment. Messages are streaming in real-time with a couple of seconds lag, but the issue is that "data watermark" stays a while (observed like 1,5 hours) behind and therefore the window is never triggered and GroupByKey does not work.

If I omit `.withTimestampAttribute(...)` when reading from PubSub, everything seems to work correct, but I have a lag on my timestamp, which causes messages to be assigned to a later window in many cases.

I found a workaround by triggering in processing time instead of event time, but I haven't assessed if this is a real solution:

```
.triggering(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().alignedTo(Duration.standardMinutes(1)).plusDelayOf(Duration.standardMinutes(1)))
.withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO)    
.discardingFiredPanes()
```

The question is how I can make sure the watermark is updates when reading from PubSub with using the timestamp attribute?

Comment: Is there a significant number of dropped event that you can tell through UI?

I cannot access your job log. One common reason I saw was watermark is established on event publish time but user code setup event timestamp again, which makes all those events are considered late events and dropped at GBK.

Comment: I have updated the question using the hints in your comment.

Comment: Sounds like the problem happens at `.withTimestampAttribute()`, as you have mentioned if you don't use it, it seems working. In that case, does your timestamp attribute follow the requirement defined here: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/pubsub/PubsubIO.java#L900

Comment: Yes, it is in RFC 3339 and parsed correctly, at least the .timestamp() method on ProcessContext gives a correct time.
The problem seems to be the watermark not advancing.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: No, I ended up using Beam for preprocessing and do the window function in sql on a database.

Comment: I used a lot of time on learning Beam and I think in principal it is elegant, but in the end I think it is NOT worth using in a business context because getting it right and debugging costs so many hours more than using other technologies. I think for most applications there is no advantage in having parallel processing either. I do like the built-in resilience in combination with Google Dataflow from an operations standpoint.